# StackExchange.redis not working

Tags: .net, stackexchange.redis

It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s); to create a disconnected multiplexer, disable AbortOnConnectFail. Timeout

My connection string is 
"(remoteMachineIP),syncTimeout=5000,connectTimeout=2000,AllowAdmin=true,ConnectRetry=0" />

Its working fine in local but giving problem as soon as I push it in Prod envirinment.

Comment: Is the port opened on the production redis: 6379? Can you connect to your redis instance from other machines?

Comment: i am able to connect from local.. its working for same remote machine.   i tried to put abortConnect=false . I avoids the error  but IsConnected still comes false. i.e. still no connection

Comment: But from other production machines can you connect to your redis? Is your redis and production environment on the same network?

Comment: No, they are in different machine.  I need to ask whether permission is allotted based on some group. If permission is not allowed does it throws this kinda error?

Comment: Yes, it looks like a possible error